# confusing behaviour of logical and (&&) and logic or (||) operators in c programming

Tags: c

Can anybody explain why the output is 'a' only, if && has higher priority than ||. Below is the code snippet.

```
       #include<stdio.h>
        int main(){
        int a = printf("a")||printf("b")&&printf("c");
        return 0;
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&&` has higher *precedence*, according to conventional terminology.  "Priority" gives a potentially (more) misleading impression.

Whatever you call it, it is not about order of operations, but rather about correctly identifying the operands of each operator.  That `&&` has higher precedence means that your declaration of `a` is equivalent to

```
int a = printf("a") || (printf("b")&&printf("c"));   // THIS
```

, as opposed to

```
int a = (printf("a")||(printf("b")) && printf("c");  // NOT THIS
```

Furthermore, the `printf("a")` is executed first either way, because the left-hand operand of `&&` and `||` is always evaluated before the right-hand one, and the right-hand operand is only evaluated at all if that is necessary to determine the result of the operation.

In your case, each `printf` call will return 1 on success (if it is executed at all).  The `printf("a")` is executed first, per the rule for the operands of an `||` operator.  Its result is enough to determine the overall result of that operation, so no part of the other operand is evaluated.

If you used parentheses to override the default grouping then the short-circuiting would be more narrowly scoped, with the result that `ac` would be printed.

Comment: Good explanation. The correct interpretation should be the first one i.e,
 int a = printf("a") || (printf("b")&&printf("c")); 
But why none of the operand of && operator is printed as it is evaluated first

Comment: @SuspectBloom993, I seem not to have conveyed my point successfully. Please re-read the second paragraph: **precedence is not about order of of execution.**  It is about grouping of operands.  By a different rule, the left-hand operand of an `||` operator is evaluated before its right-hand operand.  The right-hand operand is evaluated only if the left-hand one evaluates to zero.  The effect of precedence here is that *both* of the latter two `printf` calls are part of the right-hand operand of the `||`, so neither is executed.

Comment: I don't understand, @KrishnaKanthYenumula, are you asking for a citation to the standard? C11 paragraph 6.5.14/4: "the || operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; [...] If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated."  As I said, *by rule*, the left-hand operand is evaluated first, and the right-hand one only if the left-hand one evaluates to 0.  Similar applies to the `&&` operator, but not to most other binary operators.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  There is something called, **sequence point**, which guarantees  left-to-right evaluation for `&&` and `||` operatos. I was expecting this.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula, there is a sequence point between evaluation of the two operands only if the right-hand operand is evaluated at all.  That the left-hand one is evaluated first is a specific provision of its own, as quoted.  That does not depend on the sequence point, neither textually nor semantically.  The sequence point ensures that *all the side effects* of evaluating the left operand are complete before the right operand is evaluated.  That's convenient and natural, but not essential.

Answer (score 4):

This is a feature called ["Short Circuit Evaluation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

The code is trying to determine if the expression `X || Y && Z` is `True` or `False` so it can assign a value to variable `a`.

Because of short-circuit evaluation, once the first part, `printf("a")`, is `True` (non-zero), it does not matter what the 2nd half of the expression is, so it does not get evaluated.

`True || (*anything*)` will result in true, so why bother evaluating the 2nd half of the code?

The entire 2nd part of the expression: `printf("b")&&printf("c")` gets skipped completely, because its not needed.

As your code demonstrates very well, when part of an expression is skipped due to Short Circuiting, any side-effects of that code (such as printing to the console) get skipped as well, sometimes leading to confusing and non-obvious bugs.

Not all languages have short-circuit evaluation, but it is commonly found in most languages.

Comment: Thanks mate, but my confusion is with the precedence and associativity rule as per which && should be evaluated first.

Answer (score 1):

Precedence only affects which operators are grouped with which operands, not the order in which subexpressions are evaluated.

Both `&&` and `||` force left-to-right evaluation.  Due to precedence rules, the expression `x || y && z` is *parsed* as `x || (y && z)`, however it is *evaluated* as follows:

```
x is evaluated and all side effects are applied;
if x evaluates to 0, then
  y is evaluated and all side effects applied
  if y evaluates to non-zero, then
    z is evaluated
    if z is non-zero, then 
      the result of y && z is 1, and
      the result of x || y && z is 1
    else
      fhe result of y && z is 0, and
      the result of x || y && z is 0
    end if
  else
    z is *not* evaluated
    the result of y && z is 0, and
    the result of x || y && z is 0
  end if
else
  y && z is *not* evaluated
  x || y && z evaluates to 1
end if
```

Remember that both `&&` and `||` *short-circuit* - depending on the value of the left operand, the right operand will not be evaluated.  If `a` is `0`, then `a && b` evaluates to `0` regardless of the value of `b`, so `b` is not evaluated at all.

Similarly, if `a` is non-zero, then `a || b` evaluates to `1` regardless of the value of `b`, so `b` is not evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Sequence Point**

> A sequence point defines any point in a computer program's execution
> at which it is guaranteed that all side effects of previous
> evaluations will have been performed, and no side effects from
> subsequent evaluations have yet been performed.

At a sequence point, it is guaranteed that evaluation of all previous sub-expressions are complete.

**2) From [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/precedence-and-order-of-evaluation?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-160):**

> Only the sequential-evaluation (,), logical-AND (&&), logical-OR (||),
> conditional-expression (? :), and function-call operators constitute
> sequence points, and therefore guarantee a particular order of
> evaluation for their operands.

So, there exists a sequence point between left operand and right operand of logical OR `||` and logical AND `&&`.  Hence, logical operators guarantee evaluation of their operands from left to right.

**3)  From [C Sequence Points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/c-sequence-points?view=msvc-160)**

> The left operand of the
> logical-AND operator is completely evaluated and all side effects
> complete before continuing. If the left operand evaluates to false
> (0), the other operand is not evaluated.
>
> The left operand of the
> logical-OR operator is completely evaluated and all side effects
> complete before continuing. If the left operand evaluates to true
> (nonzero), the other operand is not evaluated.

**4) Reason:**

> int a = printf("a") || printf("b") && printf("c");

So, there is a **sequence point** between `printf("a")` and `(printf("b") && printf("c"))`.
That's why first  `printf("a")` is evaluated. Since, the left operand result is non-zero, the right operand is not evaluated [(short-circuit evaluation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: @SuspectBloom993  Hope this is clear. Please check the links for more details.

Answer (score 0):

`printf()` is a function that always returns the number of written characters (for `printf("a");` it returns `1`).

The logical operators (`||` and `&&`) in C evaluate their arguments from left to right in a way that they *cut* the evaluation at the point on which there's security on the final result.  As the first argument to `||` is true (because `1` is different than `0`), the right operand to `||` doesn't need to be evaluated, as the result will be true anyway, and this is why the right expression (`printf("b") && printf("c")`) is not evaluated at all.

For `||` if the left operand evaluation gives true, there's no need to evaluate the right argument.  For `&&` if the left operand evaluates false, then the result will be false, and there's no need to evaluate the right argument.